# GetPixel returns incorrect values

Tags: c++, getpixel

This is my first post on this forum, please don't go hard on me if I didn't post it in the right place or if I did something wrong, I don't post in forums very much. So, I have this problem with GetPixel function. Basically, it should return the color decimal at x, y. The code I am about to post works perfectly on windows 7 32bit, but recently I bought a new laptop y50-70 with windows 8.1 64bit and the same code works completely different. I can't find any solution to the problem, can't even describe it. I think it could have something to do with desktop handle, HDC, GetDC(), GetPixel(), maybe even with my computer resolution, refresh rate or something like that... I have even recorded some videos which could help you understand the problem I am having because I can't even describe it correctly. It is like the real color is x = 219, y = 407 away from the place, where my mouse is pointing. The new laptop is 3 weeks old, I even tried to do system restore 1 time, but that didn't solve the problem.

Feel free to use this code, hope it will work fine for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void Detect();

int main()
{
    Detect();

    return 0;
}

void Detect()
{
    POINT p;
    HDC hDC = GetDC(0);
    int x, y;

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT)) // Press insert to stop
    {
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        hDC = GetDC(0);
        cout << x << " " << y << " " << GetPixel(hDC, x, y) << endl;
        Sleep(50);
    }
    ReleaseDC(0, hDC);
}
```

Links to the problem below:
https://youtu.be/q2H2M8WLHVI
https://youtu.be/UcneHwXaGoM

If anyone could at least help somehow or tell what to do, where to go, I would very, very much appreaciate it. One of the main reasons why I started programming is because something like this, working with colours, conditions, etc... and now I can't advance further which is really sad. Hope to hear a reply. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but you should remove the `GetDC` from outside the loop and move the `ReleaseDC` into the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I will add ReleaseDC to the loop, and the reason why I added GetDC outside was because it was undefined, using VisualStudio 2013, but this is not a solution to the main problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom novice question, but why should the `GetDC`(and the `ReleaseDC`) be inside of the while loop? Does the return value of the `GetDC` change?

Comment: @starriet it's just that a DC is not meant to be held onto long term. I'm not sure what the effect is of trying, but it's better not to have to worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably an issue with DPI scaling.

If your new monitor has a higher-than-average number of dots per inch, then Windows, by default, will stretch the graphics.  By default, Windows assumes that programs ignore the DPI.  If Windows didn't stretch the graphics, then programs that didn't adjust for the DPI would have tiny text in tiny windows on high-density displays.

This is a bit of a hack.  Some of the Windows APIs and messages that let you ask about the display and windows will translate the coordinates between an "average" 96 pixels-per-inch and whatever the actual DPI is for the monitor.  Likewise, the APIs that let you size things do the opposite transformation.  So this is all largely transparent to the program.  But it's not perfect because not all the APIs can do the scaling in a consistent manner.

So my guess is that your laptop has a high-resolution display, GetPixel doesn't translate coordinates for DPI scaling, and the mouse position *is* transformed for DPI scaling.  The result is that you're asking for a pixel that doesn't really line up with the mouse.

My suggested solution is the tell windows that your program is "DPI-aware".  There are several ways to do this.  The easiest in your case might be to call [SetProcessDPIAware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) right at the beginning of your program.  You could also do this be marking your program in the manifest.  Depending on the compiler you're using, there might be a command line option to create the manifest you need automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much! SetProcessDPIAware() solved it! I included this function right in main() function, hope it's okay. Is there anyway I can rate your post as answer? Just want to say thanks again. :)

Comment: Because of DPI virtualization, if one application queries another with a different awareness level for DPI-dependent information, the system will automatically scale values to match the awareness level of the caller. One example of this is if you call GetWindowRect and pass in a window created by another application. Using the situation described above, assume that a PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE app created a 500 by 500 window on display C. If you query for the window rect from a different application, the size of the rect will vary based upon the DPI awareness of your app. From: http://bit.ly/1RpUnHx

Comment: @mikew:  I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.  There's no inter-application communication going on here.  Only one of the two APIs that Sakire Sileteik is using is applying scaling.

Comment: I was just posting that quote for reference from the MSDN site. I would think `GetDC` qualifies as inter-application in the same way as `GetWindowRect`, but I don't know. All I do know is that I have noticed the problem even without getting the mouse coords. I would be sending hardcoded coordinates and still getting the wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that has worked for me, is to change a setting in the Control Panel, to disable per-device DPI Scaling. Are you running multiple monitors?

Win 8.1 introduced a new setting in the Control Panel, which says "Let me choose one DPI scaling for **all** displays". By defualt this is turned off. Turning it on has worked for me.

See this video to find the setting:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE3IUTPy1WA

I'm curious, so let me know if that works for you, when you don't use `SetProccesDPIAware()`